# How to have 2 semaphores acquired by one thread? (Only simple counting semaphores)

Tags: java, semaphore

I am working on a typical homework about semaphores in Java/Linux. There is a table of coffee, milk and sugar and there are different types of participants who are looking for specific combination of those materials and of course waiters who are responsible for refilling not-full-containers.

Imagine a participant wants coffee & milk and he should wait (get blocked), for instance, if coffee is available but not milk. Is there any way that I can block his thread, using (acquiring) 2 semaphores (s_anyMilk, s_anyCoffee) simultaneously?

Without having that, I only have this stupid dead-end in mind:

```
if(Main.s_anyCoffee.availablePermits()!=0 &&
       Main.s_anyMilk.availablePermits()!=0)
    {
        Main.s_anyCoffee.acquire();
        Main.s_anyMilk.acquire();
        //do something here
        //Waiters will come later in their threads and refill containers
    }
else
{
//NO IDEA HERE!
}
```

Comment: Don't forget, that you can run into a deadlock. For example if a guy holds milk and wants coffee, another guy holds coffee and wants suger and the third guy holds suger and wants milk. None of them can satisfy his wish nor can he release his ingredient.

Comment: You are right Tom but here if someone wants coffee and Milk, only if there are more than one coffee and one milk, other participants can ask for them. Thanks for notifying.

Comment: FYI, there is a race condition in your code.  Specifically, the number of permits can change between the call to `availablePermits()` and `acquire()`.  The semaphore acquires will block until they can be acquired though, so I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @jason I am looking for a way to acquire 2 semaphores by one thread at once. To be more precise, I'm interested to know if there is any other way apart from creating 3rd semaphore which takes care of those 2 semaphores to be acquired at once?

Comment: I can't see any reason to add additional synchronization outside of the semaphores.  This is how semaphores work, and what they are used for.  I think you're overthinking the problem.

Comment: I tried to ask a clear question without describing lots of details of the main project. But I add this part:
For instance, the participant who wants coffee & milk but can find only milk, should not block any other participant who wants milk and sugar. That's the reason I cannot do `s_anyCoffee.acquire()` separately and let only one container block a thread of a participant. My last idea is creating combination of semaphores (s_anyMilk&Sugar). But I am not asking about that. My question is still there.